# vuejs v-bind:style margin-right working but not margin-left

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So I'm having trouble with a :style on one of my div elements, when I do the following :

```
:style="(index + 1) % 2 == (0) && type.Liste.length === indexVin + 1 ? `margin-left : calc((100% - (100% / ${type.Liste.length})) + 6rem);` : null"
```

this happens, as you can see the style attribute is empty

[image: no style on div]

But if I change my `margin-left` to a `margin-right` or a `padding-left` it works just fine

[image: Div with margin-right]

[image: Div with padding-left]

I read [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4184) that the `margin-left` should be in camelCase but I tried and nothing changed, weird thing is `margin-right` or `padding-left` are in kebab-case and work just fine.

I don't think it comes from my shorthand if since, once again it works whenever I set my css to anything but `margin-left` , I also tried removing any other source of css on my div (so only the one I setup here is applied) and that didn't work either.

I'm running out of solutions, and yes I absolutely need it to be a margin instead of a padding

Edit : Here's a bit more code, the weirdest thing happened, my console.log work just fine, triggering when it needs to but for some reason if I put margin-left in my `if(even)`it doesn't work however margin-left works when it enters the `else if(odd)` and it's the same for margin-right but in the opposite direction, margin-right only works when it's in the `if(even)` any idea why ?

```js
methods : {
    computedStyle(index , type , indexVin ) {
      if ((index + 1) % 2 == (0) && type.Liste.length === indexVin + 1) {
        console.log('even and last')
        return `margin-left : calc((100% - (100% / ${type.Liste.length})) + 6rem);`
      } else if (type.Liste.length === indexVin + 1) {
        console.log('odd and last')
        return `margin-right : calc((100% - (100% / ${type.Liste.length})) + 6rem);`
       // return `'margin-left' : calc((100% - (100% / ${type.Liste.length})) - 6rem);`
       //  return 'background-color : red'
      } else {
        console.log('nothing special')
        return null
      }
    },
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-block-1" v-for="(type , index) in TypesDeVins" :key="index">
      <div class="tw-flex tw-items-end slider-top"
           :class="[LeftOrRight(index) , FlexDirection(index)]">
        <div class="colonnes-resp-2 tw-flex-shrink-0" :class="LeftOrRightMargin(index , 2)">
          <h4 class="tw-uppercase tw-font-bold text-1-2 letter-spacing-3"
              :class="ColorTitle(index)">Les appellations</h4>
          <h2 class="tw-uppercase tw-text-white tw-font-bold text-2-4 tw-mb-12 letter-spacing-4">{{ type.Nom }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-container" :class="`slider-top-${index}`" :dir="rtl(index)">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="nom-vin swiper-slide" v-for="(vin , indexVin) in type.Liste"
                 :key="indexVin"
                 :class="slideDir(index)"
                 :style="computedStyle(index , type , indexVin)"
                 >
              <h3 class="tw-text-white tw-font-bold tw-uppercase letter-spacing-3 text-1-2 tw-pb-12">{{ vin.title.rendered }}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: camelCase is used in object, but in template literal in your code above, we don't need to use camelCase.
I don't think it is problem of `vue` or `margin-left`. can you show me more code or jsfiddle so I can debug?

Comment: Added more of the html, unfortunately I can't put it in a jsfiddle, I'm using it for a headless CMS which is still on a local server for now

Answer (score 0):

The documentation starts out by showing a style binding using an object:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Here's an example from the docs:

```
<div class="static" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }"
```

> 

Try this, also perhaps break out that style as a computed property to help readability and debugging.

template:

```
<div :style="computedStyle(index)"></div>
```

script:
(this needs to be added within **computed** not methods.)

```
computedStyle() {
  const listeLength = this.TypesDeVins[index].Liste.length;
  return index => {
    return (index + 1) % 2 == (0) && listeLength === indexVin + 1
        ? {'margin-left' : `calc((100% - (100% / ${listeLength})) + 6rem)`} 
        : null;
  }}
```

A couple notes:

- this computedStyle should be located within computed, not methods.
- the error you received was correct, in my example type was not defined
- type is a single item from your TypesDeVins array
- i created a const to simply define the value directly you were keying off of

i recommend throwing in a debugger if needed to step through your code here to ensure the values are coming through as you expect them to.

Based on your new code:

```
computed : {
  computedStyle() {
    return (index, indexVin) => {
      const listeLength = this.TypesDeVins[index].Liste.length;
      const spacing = `calc((100% - (100% / ${listeLength})) + 6rem)`;
      if ((index + 1) % 2 == (0) && listeLength === indexVin + 1) return {'margin-left' : spacing};
      if (listeLength === indexVin + 1) return {'margin-right' : spacing};

      return {};
    }
  }
},
```

**Pay close attention to how parameters are used within a computed**

Comment: When I do put it in a computed property it causes the whole page to bug with the error "type is undefined" :/

Comment: Oh I did miss that, I've updated my answer for you. I've added additional notes at the bottom for you to check out.

Comment: Thank you for the notes, I'm still a bit new to Vue so it's helping me a lot, your code works but I still have the same problem when I set `margin-left` to the the even condition it returns empty but if i switch `margin-left` and `margin-right` it works as it should

Comment: Have you set some debuggers to see if there are any problems that are failing silently? What does the rendered output look in your inspector?